# How to (most efficiently) download video from Periscope?

Tags: video, download, video-streaming, streaming

Majority of the search results for **"download periscope"** lead to websites allowing me to download the app.

**"download periscope stream"** is a much better search term that actually led me to two solutions but none of them are convenient.

### 1) tried and works

http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-save-my-Periscope-video-or-broadcast-to-my-phone/answer/Andrew-Leyden - that requires that the phone is connected all the time

*(for the whole 50 minutes of the stream)*

### 2) didn't try, should work

Recording screen + using http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-record-audio-from-your-computer-using-Quick/ to record audio

*(again, 50 minutes waiting)*

---

I also tried using technique described here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073330/downloading-storing-periscope-live-streaming-broadcasts - just by observing network request and populating list of URLs to download via wget:

`https://replay.periscope.tv/  ...  ==/chunk_1.ts
https://replay.periscope.tv/  ...  ==/chunk_2.ts`

But that naive version fails - they check cookie... Maybe I should use PhantomJS to accept cookie and then download the chunks? Before I start digging into that - maybe there is a straightforward, off the bat, ready to go solution I'm missing?

---

The question is generic and applies to any periscope video.

Bonus question - what if the video is mine - can I retroactively save it to the camera roll from the periscope app? (assuming "autosave broadcast" option was turned off)

Comment: It's a pain really. Here's a tutorial I created for doing this: https://youtu.be/3jrEhi7kTN8 This method works within a desktop browser. You will need to "watch" the entire replay. You cannot retroactively save your broadcasts.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my Windows batch script that supports all latest Periscope updates, plus has an option to download multiple replays, record live streams, convert .ts to .mp4 and rotate it, if necessary.

Uses console tools curl, aria2, jq, ffmpeg and two bat scripts by Dave Benham - getTimestamp and JREPL (big thanks for them).

Download (16 mb):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_x__uIHJMFxR3BadmFvZ0prRzA/view

https://yadi.sk/d/6f0QpY1hkPPUd

GitHub: https://github.com/n3tman/periscope.tv

Comment: WOW. I had a look at the code. Great work... Suggestion - do you have account on GitHub? That would allow others to collaborate with you...

Comment: @MichalStefanow, thanks! I followed your advice and created a repository here: https://github.com/n3tman/periscope.tv

Answer (score 1):

From my test I found the following:

During a live broadcast, on average the last 15-20 live chunk files are still available. A chunk is usually 3 seconds, so that means you can retrospectively go back about a minute in the past before they are deleted from the CDN. This is not always the case and some times you will not be able to go back that far. Also some are missing from the start of the broadcast, so a replay might start at chunk3 for example. I believe this is due to the lag between creating a broadcast and finalising it.

Once a broadcast ends and a replay url is available, then all replay chunks are available for download. If the broadcaster deletes the broadcast, then the access keys are revoked immediately and no more replay chunks will be able to be downloaded after that point.

Also (from memory) the cookies to the CDN may instead be passed as a query string. The CDN I'm pretty sure will accept them as those or as cookies in the header.

Answer (score 1):

[youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) supports downloading from [periscope.tv](https://www.periscope.tv/). I've tried it with live streaming and past events, and it works for both.

Answer (score 0):

I created an Android application to download Periscope videos: [Scopedown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.parallaxsolutions.scropedown)

1. In Periscope, select the desired retransmission (does not support live broadcast yet)
2. Swipe up, click *Share*
3. Click *Copy Link*
4. Paste the link in the application download area
5. Click download and wait
6. The video will be in the folder "Movies"

There's [Scopedown - PC Version (Web)](http://www.downloadperiscopevideos.com)

Comment: Can you give a little more information on what this does or how it works?

Comment: I'll try and if it works expect my upvote :)

Comment: works? please, give your feedback.
I'm thinking opening the android periscope API that I built for this project in github